# Docker failing to load apparmor profile upon ubuntu host boot

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, docker

I have a container x that fails to start automatically upon host boot.

The last message in the container's log is:

> set apparmor profile docker-default: no such file or directory

The same container x runs fine if I manually run "docker start x"

Any ideas on what's wrong with my environment ?

Answer (score 8):

I just updated to the latest version of docker (first to 0.11.0 and now to 0.11.0) and I am experiencing the same thing on Linux Mint 15 Olivia. Installing apparmor seems to have fixed the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

Comment: I have apparmor installed and I still have this exact issue. It only occurs on host boot, and docker start works fine. I also set apparmor to complain mode and it still fails

Comment: Same here. I already had apparmor installed when the problem appeared.

Comment: There seems to be some other kind of bug in 14.04 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5788

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using `fig`... I was having the same issue because a wrong "volumes" entry in my fig.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres:9
  volumes: ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

After changing it to the following code, docker could start the "db" container:

```
db:
  image: postgres:9
  volumes:
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, installing apparmor is not enough, since the problem happens even with apparmor installed. More exactly, the error happens because of the docker daemon being loaded before apparmor set its config [as explained here](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/400).

Full solution:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

and:

```
sudo service apparmor restart # Just in case
sudo service docker restart
```

Should work after that. At least, for me it did.